# Custom theme: Alternatives to long list of 'include' in functions.php

Tags: php, theme-development, include

I'm building a custom theme for in-house use only. I started by putting a lot of the core functions in plugins, but then that seemed silly since they don't require any user interaction.

Next, I put all of my classes in different php files in my theme folder and `include` them all in functions.php.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you use an auto-loader?

Answer (score 1):

> As @toscho mentioned in his comment, your best bet is probably an
>   [autoloader](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_path#Examples)
>   of some sort...

```
foreach ( glob( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . "subfolder/*.php" ) as $file ) {
    include_once $file;
}
```

There are plugins that [do this kind of thing](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-autoloader/) or possilby something like [code snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/), but I'll add some examples below...

### Example for basic functions in separate files in a plugin:

This example lets you easily add and remove features using theme-support. so basically in your `functions.php` you can this....

```
add_theme_support( feature-one );
add_theme_support( feature-two );
add_theme_support( feature-three );
```

***Create a basic plugin with the following structure:***

```
plugin-name/
    ├── plugin-name.php
    ├── features/feature-one.php
    ├── features/feature-two.php
    ├── features/feature-three.php
    └── features/feature-four.php
```

***Inside `plugin-name.php include this code:`***

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name:        My Themename Addons
Plugin URI:         https://example.com/
Description:        Add Themename support
Version:            1.0.0
Author:             bryanwillis
Author URI:         https://github.com/bryanwillis/
License:            MIT License
License URI:        http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
*/

function mytheme_autoload_files() {
  global $_wp_theme_features;
  foreach (glob(__DIR__ . '/theme-support/*.php') as $file) {
    $feature = 'mytheme-' . basename($file, '.php');
    if (isset($_wp_theme_features[$feature])) {
      require_once $file;
    }
  }
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_autoload_files', 100);
```

---

### Second Example with functions in separate folders (like entire plugins):

This example doesn't have the option to remove features on the fly, but it automatically loads everything...

1. Add a folder in your theme called `theme-plugins`.
2. Create a file called `autoloader.php` inside theme-plugins folder with the below code and use include/require/etc. in your functions.php to include it ( you could also make this it's own plugin).
3. Drop your plugins inside the `theme-plugins` folder to autoload them ( plugins must have the same folder name as file name.

***Folder structure:***

```
themename/
 └── theme-plugins/
    ├── autoloader.php
    ├── plugin-one/plugin-one.php
    ├── plugin-two/plugin-two.php
    ├── plugin-three/plugin-three.php
    └── plugin-foo/plugin-foo.php
```

***Code for `autoloader.php`:***

```
 <?php
/**
 * Autoloader - theme-plugins/autoloader.php
 */
 function themename_plugins_autoloader() {
    $plugins_dirs =  = array_filter( scandir() );
    $non_dirs = array(
        '.',
        '..',
        '.DS_Store',
    );
    for( $i = 0; $i < count( $non_dirs ); $i++ ) {
        $not_dir_key = array_search( $non_dirs[ $i ], $$autoload_plugin_dirs );
        if( $not_dir_key !== false ) {
            unset( $$autoload_plugin_dirs[ $not_dir_key ] );
        }
        unset( $not_dir_key );
    }
    unset( $non_dirs );
    if( empty( $$autoload_plugin_dirs ) ) {
        return;
    }
    sort( $$autoload_plugin_dirs );
    foreach( $$autoload_plugin_dirs as $dir ) {
        $plugin_dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . $dir;
        $plugin_file = trailingslashit( $plugin_dir ) . $dir . '.php';
        if( is_dir( $plugin_dir ) && file_exists( $plugin_file ) ) {
            require_once( $plugin_file );
        }
        unset( $plugin_file, $plugin_dir );
    }
}
themename_plugins_autoloader();
```

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks so much. I can't wait to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I store core functions in a parent theme, then load site-specific functions to a child theme.

Benefits:

1. Decluttering the (child) theme with code that hardly ever changes
   per in-house preferences.
2. Ability to push new core functionality to
   many installations by simply updating the parent theme.